# Java - parse nested xml file and write to the file

Tags: java, xml, javax

I have a .xml file like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Event>
    <Issue>ggg</Issue>
    <City>Athen</City>   
      <Group>
      <AlternateIdentification>
        <AlternateID>DG800</AlternateID>
        <AlternateIDType>GoA</AlternateIDType>
      </AlternateIdentification>
      <AlternateIdentification>
        <AlternateID>SS500</AlternateID>
        <AlternateIDType>SDD</AlternateIDType>
      </AlternateIdentification>
      <AlternateIdentification>
        <AlternateID>TY158</AlternateID>
        <AlternateIDType>YTU</AlternateIDType>
      </AlternateIdentification>
      </Group>
    </Event>
```

And I would like to parse .xml file and write the output to the flat .txt file with lines like this:

```
ggg Athen DG800
ggg Athen SS500
ggg Athen TY158
```

Can you help me and tell me how to do this with javax DOM parser? I have no idea how to start :( This common part confuses me the most because I need to iterate this file in this case 3 times to get 3x "`ggg Athen`" and then additional tag `AlternateID`?

Comment: Can you use a more sophisticated XML library such as GSON or Jackson for the task?

Comment: If not, the [Java tutorial for XML->DOM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html) is a good starting point.

Comment: But in which file do you want to write the output ? In another file I assume ?

Comment: @davidxxx yes, the output should be in another flat file - .txt

Comment: Try to write code first , then ask questions, there are plenty of tutorial available, refer this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

Answer (score 2):

> Java - parse nested xml file and write to the file

A simple way :

1. Read line by line with `BufferedReader.readLine()` until finding the start of the nested xml part.
   For example :  `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
2. When you identified this line, add each read line in a `StringBuilder` instance until you encounter the end of the xml part that you want to analyse. For example the end tag of the root element of it.
   Here : `</Event>`
3. Create a `org.w3c.dom.Document` from the `String` contained in the `StringBuilder` :

   `DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

   Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader( stringBuilder.toString())));`
4. Use your preferred way to find data in the document : dom, jdom, xpath, etc...

Comment: I don't even understand the first point from your answer :(
Read line by line until the start of the nested xml part. For example <?xml version="1.0"?> ?? It's the begining of the xml file not only the nested part

Comment: Ah I though that  you had nested xml in your xml... It  should easier so.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to look at Sax XML Parser. Tutorial for that can be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)

Good luck

Comment: But how to do this with javax DOM parser??